# Java 7 => Java 8 : for to foreach on a Map with calculation

Tags: dictionary, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I begin with Java 8 and i have a migration project. I have read a lot of documentation and tutorial to use foreach or streams but i have a little last problem. I don't find the answer, just tutorial easy example.

I'm trying to transform this loop :

```
for ( Map.Entry<Neuron, Double> entry: this.entries.entrySet() ) {
     value += entry.getKey().getExitValue() * entry.getValue();
}
```

This solution doesn't match and i know why (anonymous class => final/local var)

```
this.entries.forEach( (neuron, weight) -> {
      value += neuron.getExitValue() * weight;
});
```

But only with a foreach i don't know how do this simple operation.

I think it's very easy but...

I have try with stream but i have similar problems.

```
Double sum = entries.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .forEach( entry-> { ? } );
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Don’t replace loops with `forEach`. That’s not an improvement. If you’re going towards functional programming, you better forget that `forEach` exists. Since you are *summing* values calculated from the entries, you should think into that direction, i.e. `value = entries.entrySet().stream() .mapToDouble(e -> e.getKey().getExitValue() * e.getValue()) .sum()`

Comment: @Holger this should be an answer.

Comment: Hello, right answer. I was thinking this week end and it's not usefull to migrate this loop (because not functional programming in this case). Your solution with mapToDouble match correctly too. Have a nice day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Holger said in the comments above - in this case it is better to use `mapToDoble`. However there is still a way to do it using `forEach` loop. *Please note that it is an ugly, dirty trick and it is just for demonstration purposes and it shouldn't be used in production code.* As we know only final or effectively final variables can be used with lambda expressions, that's why `value +=` is an illegal expression. Java-8 added a few new classes to `java.util.concurrent.atomic` one of them is [DoubleAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/DoubleAdder.html). You can use it with lambda:

```
DoubleAdder adder = new DoubleAdder();
stream.forEach(e -> adder.add(e.getKey().getExitValue() * e.getValue()));
System.out.println(adder.sum());
```

***I don't see any cases when this should be used instead of mapToDouble***

Comment: Interresting approach, certainly ugly but tricky.

_The order of accumulation within or across threads is not guaranteed. Thus, this class may not be applicable if numerical stability is required, especially when combining values of substantially different orders of magnitude_
Unfortunately, we need it for this application (neural network).
Thanks to you for this answer, very interresting for me.

Answer (score 0):

I introduced a list to stall the values and then do calculation with list.

```
final List<BigDecimal> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
otherList.stream().forEach(val-> valuesList.add(map.get(val)));
final BigDecimal lastValue = valuesList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add);
```